# Looking for an introductory Algebraic Geometry book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am looking for recommendations on an AG text to work through this summer, possibly with the help of a mentor. I would want this book to have some introduction to categories, and then develop the modern methods (some development of sheaves and schemes), hopefully up to some realization of Riemann-Roch. Any recommendations?

Comment: What is your background ?

Comment: undergraduate algebra, differential topology, classical differential geometry, nothing up there. I may need to read up a little on more detailed aspects of ring theory it seems.

Answer (score 4):

The book [*Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/) by Ravi Vakil is likely to become the standard as a comprehensive text in algebraic geometry.  It may be more thorough than what you have in mind (and it certainly is not something that can be fully digested by mere mortals in a single summer of self-study), but it covers all the topics you want, is very well-written, and is freely available for download.

Comment: How does this compare to Hartshone's book? I ask as both are now freely available

Comment: Vakil's book is more comprehensive and more modern.  I think either book would do well for a second course in algebraic geometry, but for most people, a more concrete introduction is likely to be helpful at first.  I like Hassett's *Introduction to Algebraic Geometry*, which covers the subject from a computational perspective.

Answer (score 4):

[These notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/agag/mitglieder/professoren/gathmann/notes/alggeom/) by Andreas Gathmann are precisely what you're asking for. He starts very gently, schemes being introduced in Chapter 5, but he ends with sheaf cohomology (including Riemann-Roch) and some intersection theory.

Comment: I think I'm going to work through these with Hartshorne as a reference. Thank you!